# Kafka.conn FetchResponse_v2 get "message_set=b' ' " with python consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

kafka-python 1.4.6
Python 3.7.3
debezium/kafka 0.9

I'm using kafka-python setting my consumer configuration like its docs, but I'm not getting any message, my log level is DEBUG and when I run my script, I get this output:

I have not idea that's wrong.

I tried add more configurations parameters like `request_timeout_ms`, `enable_auto_commit=False`, etc.

```
...
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,651: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <disconnected> [unspecified None]>: creating new socket
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,651: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,651: kafka.conn - INFO: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]>: connecting to kafka:9092 [('172.30.0.3', 9092) IPv4]
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,652: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,653: kafka.conn - INFO: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,653: kafka.client - DEBUG: Node bootstrap-0 connected
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,653: kafka.client - DEBUG: Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile']) to node bootstrap-0
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,653: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile'])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:04,653: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile'])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,167: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Received correlation id: 1
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,167: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Processing response MetadataResponse_v1
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,169: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Response 1 (515.169620513916 ms): MetadataResponse_v1(brokers=[(node_id=1, host='172.30.0.3', port=9092, rack=None)], controller_id=1, topics=[(error_code=5, topic='dbhistory.beta-api.profile', is_internal=False, partitions=[])])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,271: kafka.client - DEBUG: Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile']) to node bootstrap-0
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,272: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile'])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,274: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Request 2: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile'])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,281: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Received correlation id: 2
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,281: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Processing response MetadataResponse_v1
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,282: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Response 2 (7.951021194458008 ms): MetadataResponse_v1(brokers=[(node_id=1, host='172.30.0.3', port=9092, rack=None)], controller_id=1, topics=[(error_code=5, topic='dbhistory.beta-api.profile', is_internal=False, partitions=[])])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,386: kafka.client - DEBUG: Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['dbhistory.beta-api.profile']) to node bootstrap-0
...
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:05,815: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=172.30.0.3:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Request 2: FetchRequest_v2(replica_id=-1, max_wait_time=500, min_bytes=1, topics=[(topic='dbhistory.beta-api.profile', partitions=[(partition=0, offset=0, max_bytes=1048576)])])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:06,326: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Received correlation id: 2
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:06,326: kafka.protocol.parser - DEBUG: Processing response FetchResponse_v2
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:06,327: kafka.conn - DEBUG: <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=172.30.0.3:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.30.0.3', 9092)]> Response 2 (511.2500190734863 ms): FetchResponse_v2(throttle_time_ms=0, topics=[(topics='dbhistory.beta-api.profile', partitions=[(partition=0, error_code=0, highwater_offset=0, message_set=b'')])])
test_1       | 2019-07-10 15:34:06,330: kafka.metrics.metrics - DEBUG: Added sensor with name topic.dbhistory.beta-api.profile.bytes-fetched
```

My python consumer is this:

#### main.py

```
import consumer
import logging


def index():

    consum = consumer.Consumer()
    consum.run("dbhistory.beta-api.profile")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.DEBUG
    )
    index()
```

#### consumer.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


class Consumer:

    def run(self, topic):
        topic = topic

        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            topic,
            bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
            api_version=(0, 10, 0),
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        )

        print("Topic: {}".format(topic))

        print("### Getting messages...")
        print("Consumer")
        print(consumer)

        for msg in consumer:
            print("#### Message: ####")
            print(msg)
            print("#### EndMessage ####")
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:0.9
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:0.9
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER: kafka:9092
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    links:
        - zookeeper
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect:0.9
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1 
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs 
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_status
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      PLUGIN_PATH: "/plugins"
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
  test:
    build: .
    command: python3 main.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

I expect the output for message contains table information of my database.